# How to make a remote server be invisible to a user

Tags: architecture

I have a webserver `www.example.com` that takes user input and calculates results on a remote server:
`<form action="www2.example.com/action.cgi">`

Now the user is on the second server. How do I keep the user on the main server (or make `www2` invisible to the user)?

One possibility is to do an Ajax query in the background, but that would mean results are transferred from `www2` to `www` and then to the user, which adds delay and bandwidth costs.

What are some possibilities to accomplish this?

Also, if, in future, we have multiple remote servers `www2`, `www3`, etc. what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: An alternative to Ajax, is RESTful services.  But like AJAX, you will see a slight delay.  In my experience doing this, even on larger corporate networks, this delay wasn't noticeable to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

You can't truly do this without routing the query through your server taking your bandwidth.

In addition to your ajax solution you could use a reverse proxy to achieve something similar. A reverse proxy can act as a load balancer so its a good fit for your future needs as well.